# Raspberry Pi Model 2B Hostapd installation error: Unable to locate package

Tags: pi-2, wifi, raspbian-stretch, sudo, packages

So, I am trying to set up my raspberry pi model 2B as a wifi hotspot.  All the articles recommended installing and using hostapd and dnsmasq.  I was able to install the dnsmasq package without any problems, but when I tries to install hostapd, I got this error...

```
E: Unable to locate package hostapd
```

I realize that the error means that the package was not able to be located, but all the other forums I looed at said that everything I typed into the terminal was correct.  Is it that hostapd is depreciated, or not exists anymore?

NOTE: I already ran the commands to update and upgrade the Pi, and I did not run into any problems.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running?  Raspbian?  Which version?

Comment: I am running Raspbian Stretch on the model 2B.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apt database is up to date with:

`sudo apt-get update`

and then try installing hostapd again.  There was a change recently that required the database to be updated.